# mysql group rows of groups

Tags: mysql, group-by

At [Mysql group rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58161160/5568527) I have awsome answer and now I am block with other part. Same as before I have:

```
idlap   idRider session time
1        45652    1      4
2        54645    1      2
3        45652    2      2
4        54582    2      1
5        51284    1      3
6        54582    1      3
7        54645    2      4
8        51284    2      5
9        54582    2      2
```

and now I need count how many laps in the slower session and number of sesion. Result should be some:

```
id    lowest sesion    count laps
45652       1              1
54645       2              1
51284       1              1
54582       1              1
```

I try lots differents ways considering Nick strategy but nothing working.
Thanks for some help.

Comment: post code here for strategy u have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just change the `MIN` to `MAX` in that query. Note that `51284`'s slowest time is actually in session 2 (time = 5), not session 1.

```
SELECT l.idRider, l.session, l.time, s.numlaps
FROM laps l
JOIN (SELECT idRider, `session`, MAX(time) AS slowest, COUNT(*) AS numlaps
      FROM laps
      GROUP BY idRider, `session`) s ON s.idRider = l.idRider AND s.session = l.session AND s.slowest = l.time
JOIN (SELECT idRider, MAX(time) AS slowest
      FROM laps
      GROUP BY idRider) f ON f.idRider = s.idRider AND f.slowest = s.slowest
ORDER BY idRider
```

Output:

```
idRider session time    numlaps
45652   1       4       1
51284   2       5       1
54582   1       3       1
54645   2       4       1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gRneT6hpTmWArZdt5uK6p9/1)

Comment: I do not understand how it works at all, but works perfect!